# Simple navigation in Windows 8 web view

Tags: windows, windows-8, webview, windows-store-apps

I'm working on porting a Windows Phone 8 application to tablet, and I've bumped into a problem with the `WebView` API. In Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.1, the `WebBrowser` and `WebView` controls both have a `GoBack()` method. However, I need my application to be compatible for Windows 8, whose `WebView` API does not have such a method. Are there any alternatives/workarounds that anyone's used for Windows 8 apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just ended up writing a wrapper for the WebView to manage the navigation stack. Here's the relevant code, for anyone who's interested. Note that I only needed to handle backwards navigation, so I used a `Stack`. If forwards navigation is also required, it'd probably make sense to replace the `Stack` with a `List` and store the index of the current page instead.

```
public class WebViewWrapper
{
    private Stack<Uri> _navigationStack;
    private Uri _currentUri;

    public WebView WebView { get; private set; }
    public bool CanGoBack
    {
        get { return _navigationStack.Count > 0; }
    }

    public WebViewWrapper(WebView _webView)
    {
        _navigationStack = new Stack<Uri>();
        WebView = _webView;
        WebView.LoadCompleted += (object s, NavigationEventArgs e) => {
            if (_currentUri != null)
            {
                _navigationStack.Push(_currentUri);
            }
            _currentUri = e.Uri;
        };
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        if (CanGoBack)
        {
            _currentUri = null;
            WebView.Navigate(_navigationStack.Pop());
        }
    }
}
```

An example of usage would be as follows:

```
// Code behind for a view called WebBrowserPage
public sealed partial class WebBrowserPage : Page 
{
    private WebViewWrapper _webViewWrapper;

    public WebBrowserPage()
    {
        // webView is a WebView in the xaml with x:Name="webView"
        _webViewWrapper = new WebViewWrapper(webView);  
    }

    // Other code for navigating to a Uri specified in a ViewModel.

    // Event handler for a back button press
    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_webViewWrapper.CanGoBack)
        {
            _webViewWrapper.GoBack();
        }
        else 
        {
            // Code that executes a command in the ViewModel to leave the WebBrowserPage
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has a `WebBrowser` control that does some of that, but I haven't used it in any app, so I can't vouch for its quality.